# How to differentiate different comboboxes delegated to one comboBoxSelectionDidChange:

Tags: objective-c

Can I delegate two NSComboBoxes to one comboBoxSelectionDidChange: method and run an if statement to differentiate between the two boxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this may be a case where you can use `NSNotification`'s object method to obtain a pointer to the combo box that triggered the notification.

For example:

Assuming you have something like this in your .h file:

```
@interface MDAppController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSComboBox   *comboBox1;
    IBOutlet NSComboBox   *comboBox2;
} 

@end
```

In your .m file:

```
- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSComboBox *comboBox = (NSComboBox *)[notification object];
    if (comboBox == comboBox1) {
        // do something
    } else if (comboBox == comboBox2) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```